# Internet Explorer 6 PNG fix + CSS only (except IE6) drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-6, png

Hoping to get some help here.

Currently I'm developing a website using transparent PNGs for backgrounds and so. Of course this isn't working in Internet Explorer 6, so a PNG fix is being used. Also, there is a drop-down menu consisting of 2 lists, which on li:hover drops-down. For this there is a little Javascript fix used by Internet Explorer 6.

The problem occurring now is that the drop-down menu hides behind the content container, this happened after adding the PNG fix in the website. Now for example the PNG fix uses z-index, which I tried to remove to fix the problem (which didn't solve it), besides that I tried some other things which didn't lead to anything. Searching for it on Google didn't yield any useable results either.

Maybe somebody here can help, the website using it can be found here: bernadettamaas.trumpetcms.nl (please do NOT link it). The second menu item drops-down.

Thanks so far

Stefan

Comment: Also tried, or the PNG fix doesn't work (background position isn't supported at many for instance) or the drop-down menu is hidden as well

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and pretty much just went through adding `position: relative;` and `z-index`'s to each element till the menu showed above other elements which only IE6 needed as it worked in every other browser.

Are the divs posiitoned the same? Otherwise the `z-index` values won't apply correctly.

Comment: Didn't solve the problem.. added relative and a high z-index to the menu AND tried adding relative and a high z-index to everything but the menu..

Comment: Eventually I didn't solve the problem at all, it is now fixed not using a dropdown in IE6 and instead using a subpage with the submenu's options. Thanks for you're time guys :-)